# Grouping method to maintain nested elements XSLT 2.0 - separating the excess

Tags: xslt, sequence, xslt-grouping

I'm grouping bulleted items and embedding them as a second list of bulleted items inside some list elements.  I can get the items to group, but my recursion template is selecting everything from my current position in the doc to the end.  I need to set an ending point for my nested lists.

My output looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>First Bullet:<ul>
         <li>Sub-bullet 1: info for sub-bullet
                                            1</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 2: info for sub-bullet
                                            2</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 3: info for sub-bullet
                                            3</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 4: info for sub-bullet
                                                4</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 5: info for sub-bullet
                                            5</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 6: info for sub-bullet
                                            6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Second Bullet:<ul>
         <li>Sub-bullet 5: info for sub-bullet
                                            5</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 6: info for sub-bullet
                                            6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But it SHOULD look like this (without Sub-bullets 5 and 6 under the first li):

```
<ul>
    <li>First Bullet:<ul>
         <li>Sub-bullet 1: info for sub-bullet
                                            1</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 2: info for sub-bullet
                                            2</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 3: info for sub-bullet
                                            3</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 4: info for sub-bullet
                                                4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Second Bullet:<ul>
         <li>Sub-bullet 5: info for sub-bullet
                                            5</li>
         <li>Sub-bullet 6: info for sub-bullet
                                            6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure how to properly group the sub-bullets in XSLT to get them in the correct position.

Here's my source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
  xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0"
  xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0"
  xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
  xmlns:smil="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:smil-compatible:1.0"
  xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
  xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0"
  xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
  xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0">
  <office:body>
    <office:presentation>
      <draw:page draw:name="Slide1" draw:style-name="a1271"
        draw:master-page-name="Master1-Layout3-cust-Bullet"
        presentation:presentation-page-layout-name="Master1-PPL3">
        <draw:frame draw:id="id109" presentation:style-name="a1039"
                    draw:name="Content Placeholder 1" svg:x="0.31258in" svg:y="1.29095in"
                    svg:width="9.33243in" svg:height="3.8175in" presentation:class="outline"
                    presentation:placeholder="false">
                    <draw:text-box>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1012">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:p text:style-name="a1011" text:class-names=""
                                    text:cond-style-name=""><text:span text:style-name="a1010"
                                        text:class-names="">First Bullet:</text:span></text:p>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1015">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1015">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1014" text:class-names=""
                                            text:cond-style-name=""><text:span
                                                text:style-name="a1013" text:class-names=""
                                                >Sub-bullet 1: info for sub-bullet
                                            1</text:span></text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1018">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1018">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1017" text:class-names=""
                                            text:cond-style-name=""><text:span
                                                text:style-name="a1016" text:class-names=""
                                                >Sub-bullet 2: info for sub-bullet
                                            2</text:span></text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1021">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1021">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1020" text:class-names=""
                                            text:cond-style-name=""><text:span
                                                text:style-name="a1019" text:class-names=""
                                                >Sub-bullet 3: info for sub-bullet
                                            3</text:span></text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1025">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1025">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1024" text:class-names=""
                                            text:cond-style-name=""><text:span
                                                text:style-name="a1022" text:class-names=""
                                                >Sub-bullet 4: info for sub-bullet
                                                4</text:span><text:span text:style-name="a1023"
                                                text:class-names=""/></text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1029">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:p text:style-name="a1028" text:class-names=""
                                    text:cond-style-name=""><text:span text:style-name="a1026"
                                        text:class-names="">Second Bullet:</text:span><text:span
                                        text:style-name="a1027" text:class-names=""/></text:p>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1032">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1032">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1031" text:class-names=""
                                            text:cond-style-name=""><text:span
                                                text:style-name="a1030" text:class-names=""
                                                >Sub-bullet 5: info for sub-bullet
                                            5</text:span></text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1035">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1035">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1034" text:class-names=""
                                            text:cond-style-name=""><text:span
                                                text:style-name="a1033" text:class-names=""
                                                >Sub-bullet 6: info for sub-bullet
                                            6</text:span></text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                    </draw:text-box>
                    <svg:desc/>
                </draw:frame>
      </draw:page>
    </office:presentation>
  </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

Here's my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
    xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
    xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
    xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
    xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" 
    xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0"
    xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0"
    xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0"
    xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0"
    xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
    xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0"
    office:class="text"
    office:version="1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="draw:frame">
<ul>
 <xsl:for-each-group select="draw:text-box/text:list" group-starting-with="text:list-item">
  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="text:list-item[not(text:list)]"/>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group> 
</ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="draw:text-box/text:list/text:list-item/text:list/text:list-item/text:p">
<li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="draw:text-box/text:list/text:list-item/text:p">
<li><xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <!-- Check for nested list -->
    <xsl:if test="../../following-sibling::text:list[text:list-item/text:list]">

            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text:list-item/text:p"/>
            </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</li>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in 2.0?  I've attempted to create some count variables, but haven't had any luck yet on establishing an endpoint outside of the current-group context.  I know there must be an obvious (and more elegant) way to get this done.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a short, simple and easy solution that doesn't require XSLT 2.0 at all:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
 exclude-result-prefixes="text"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text:list">
  <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text:list-item[not(text:list)]">
  <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "text()[not(ancestor::text:list-item)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0"
xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0"
xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
xmlns:smil="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:smil-compatible:1.0"
xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0"
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0">
    <office:body>
        <office:presentation>
            <draw:page draw:name="Slide1" draw:style-name="a1271"         draw:master-page-name="Master1-Layout3-cust-Bullet"         presentation:presentation-page-layout-name="Master1-PPL3">
                <draw:frame draw:id="id109" presentation:style-name="a1039"                     draw:name="Content Placeholder 1" svg:x="0.31258in" svg:y="1.29095in"                     svg:width="9.33243in" svg:height="3.8175in" presentation:class="outline"                     presentation:placeholder="false">
                    <draw:text-box>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1012">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:p text:style-name="a1011" text:class-names=""                                     text:cond-style-name="">
                                    <text:span text:style-name="a1010"                                         text:class-names="">First Bullet:</text:span>
                                </text:p>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1015">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1015">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1014" text:class-names=""                                             text:cond-style-name="">
                                            <text:span                                                 text:style-name="a1013" text:class-names=""                                                 >Sub-bullet 1: info for sub-bullet                                             1</text:span>
                                        </text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1018">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1018">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1017" text:class-names=""                                             text:cond-style-name="">
                                            <text:span                                                 text:style-name="a1016" text:class-names=""                                                 >Sub-bullet 2: info for sub-bullet                                             2</text:span>
                                        </text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1021">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1021">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1020" text:class-names=""                                             text:cond-style-name="">
                                            <text:span                                                 text:style-name="a1019" text:class-names=""                                                 >Sub-bullet 3: info for sub-bullet                                             3</text:span>
                                        </text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1025">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1025">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1024" text:class-names=""                                             text:cond-style-name="">
                                            <text:span                                                 text:style-name="a1022" text:class-names=""                                                 >Sub-bullet 4: info for sub-bullet                                                 4</text:span>
                                            <text:span text:style-name="a1023"                                                 text:class-names=""/>
                                        </text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1029">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:p text:style-name="a1028" text:class-names=""                                     text:cond-style-name="">
                                    <text:span text:style-name="a1026"                                         text:class-names="">Second Bullet:</text:span>
                                    <text:span                                         text:style-name="a1027" text:class-names=""/>
                                </text:p>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1032">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1032">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1031" text:class-names=""                                             text:cond-style-name="">
                                            <text:span                                                 text:style-name="a1030" text:class-names=""                                                 >Sub-bullet 5: info for sub-bullet                                             5</text:span>
                                        </text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                        <text:list text:style-name="a1035">
                            <text:list-item>
                                <text:list text:style-name="a1035">
                                    <text:list-item>
                                        <text:p text:style-name="a1034" text:class-names=""                                             text:cond-style-name="">
                                            <text:span                                                 text:style-name="a1033" text:class-names=""                                                 >Sub-bullet 6: info for sub-bullet                                             6</text:span>
                                        </text:p>
                                    </text:list-item>
                                </text:list>
                            </text:list-item>
                        </text:list>
                    </draw:text-box>
                    <svg:desc/>
                </draw:frame>
            </draw:page>
        </office:presentation>
    </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ul>
   <li>First Bullet:</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Sub-bullet 1: info for sub-bullet                                             1</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Sub-bullet 2: info for sub-bullet                                             2</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Sub-bullet 3: info for sub-bullet                                             3</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Sub-bullet 4: info for sub-bullet                                                 4</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Second Bullet:</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Sub-bullet 5: info for sub-bullet                                             5</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Sub-bullet 6: info for sub-bullet                                             6</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

**and the browser displays this as**:

- First Bullet:

  - Sub-bullet 1: info for sub-bullet                                             1

  - Sub-bullet 2: info for sub-bullet                                             2

  - Sub-bullet 3: info for sub-bullet                                             3

  - Sub-bullet 4: info for sub-bullet                                                 4

- Second Bullet:

  - Sub-bullet 5: info for sub-bullet                                             5

  - Sub-bullet 6: info for sub-bullet                                             6

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there any way to keep the ul tag embedded in the first-level li?  Your solution works for html, but my content has validation rules that will not allow this.  So I can only use `<ul><li>First Bullet:<ul>...sub-bullets...</ul></li></ul>` at that first level of li tags.  If this can't be accomplished in the first time around, perhaps I could build a second stylesheet to somehow organize the proper nested structure.  Apologies for the late response, I was out for the holiday.

Comment: @unknown_varmit: I am sorry, but your XML document is extremely complicated and I cannot spend enormous amount of time on this. If you could provide the simplest possible example, that has no extraneous elements and does not require constant horizontal scrolling, then it might be possible to do something. The task is probably not difficult at all, however the difficulty here comes from the weird XML document. The best way of processing it is to do so with closed eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You need a template that matches a text-list; this would output the <ul> tag.